# Python: How to consolidate things in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a following list:

```
>>> list_of_list = [  ['a', 2], ['b', 3], ['a', 4, 5]  ]
```

I want the following result:
1. It can tell me there are 2 different items: 'a' and 'b'
2. There are 2 items in 'a' and 1 item in 'b'
    'a' = [2, 4, 5]
    'b' = 3

Thanks

Comment: The funny way: `dict((x,[z[1] for z in y]) for x, y in groupby(sorted(lst), lambda x: x[0]))`

Comment: What you need it a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can (should) use a dictionary, and map the first item in each sub-list (the 'key') to the second item in each sub-list (the 'value').

using a `defaultdict` will save you the trouble of instantiating each new key with an empty list.

also, as eumiro pointed out, in order to be consistent, the value of `'b'` should be a list with the single item `3` and not just the number `3`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in list_of_list:
  d[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

Comment: Great. Now explain to the OP, that it is a good idea to keep the values within a dictionary consistent (i.e. `d['b']` should be `[3]` and not `3`).

Comment: @eumiro: I don't think that's necessary, he/she will probably learn it the hard way :)

Comment: Good answer, +1 from me, but an explanation would go nicely too.

Comment: Thanks but I tried d[item[0]].append(item[1:]) but it doesn't work so well.

Comment: @Winston you keep updating your question, the solution i suggested works for the original version. adjusting it to for work with sub-lists of more than two items isn't difficult, put some thought into it.

Comment: Sorry but I just found a error on my code that's why I need to modify a little bit. Sorry about that.